# Jquery mobile MVC

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-mobile

I'm building native mobile application with JQM and Phonegap. Is there any javascript mvc framework which could properly work with JQM? Any experience would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by framework? MVC is the server-side framework and JQM is the client-side framework.

Comment: JQM is just presentation layer, I think, which works properly in all mobile devices. My app grows and due to that i need framework like, emberjs, knockout, backbone, javascript-mvc and so on... where i could connect JQM as presentation and app logic as framework.